# R raw text file missing lines after read

Tags: r, text

I am currently looking into some text mining and attempting to read in a flat file with raw texts, however when I read the file in, I am missing more than half the rows after read. The file looks similar to this;

```
ddjkfj; this is a raw line of text ? fjpflij 
jfioej33 this is another line of text jdkfjd
etc.
```

I am trying to read in, using this method,

```
data <- read.table('text.txt',sep='\n',fill=T)
```

How can I read this in without it skipping or joining lines?

Comment: `\n` is an end of line separator. Try with a different one, like ; or |. And don't use fill = T.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want the output to be. If you want a data frame where every row is a row from your text and you just want any white space to be a separator, then use `sep=""` (which is the default). If you want every row to be one single element, the answer posted by @user3949008 works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using readLines instead:

```
lines <- readLines('fileToRead.txt')
lines
[1] "ddjkfj; this is a raw line of text ? fjpflij "
[2] "jfioej33 this is another line of text jdkfjd"
```